# Specifying simulation end time in terms of number of events in omnet++

Tags: omnet++, event-simulation

In `omnetpp.ini`, to end a simulation we specify:

```
sim-time-limit = 10s (say)
```

How to specify this in terms of number of events. Does OMNeT++ have a related parameter in built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, OMNeT++ does not have ready to use parameter to stop a simulation after specified number of events.
However, it is possible to achieve that behaviour programmatically, by adding the following piece of code to every `handleMessage()`:

```
if (getSimulation()->getEventNumber() > 20000) {
    endSimulation();
}
```

Comment: Probably it would be better to implement a custom scheduler and use that. In that case you would not have to insert the above code in each module's handle message.